# How Can I Calculate remain days of the year from stored Date in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables orders and shares. order table has column called 'Order_Date', while share table has column called 'HoldingPeriod' so how can I determine the remaining days of customer order (Order_Date) from 365 days.
Please, Help I don't have any idea on how to initiate code on this but here is query from share table;

```
 <?php
$SeeShare=ViewShares();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($SeeShare))
{
    $share = $row['ShareName'];
    $numshares = $row['NumberShares'];
    $askprice = $row['AskPrice'];
    $bidprice = $row['BidPrice'];
    $commfee = $row['CommFee'];
    $ShareInterest=$row['CommPercent'];
    $Maturity=$row['HoldingPeriod'];
}?>
```

Here is the code for querying Paid Orders

```
<?php

 $status='';
$Paid=QueryPaidFor($status);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($Paid))
  {

      $share=$row['ShareName'];
      $sharenum=$row['NumberShares'];
      $amount=$row['Order_Price'];
      $status=$row['status'];
      $orderdate=$row['OrderDate'];

     }

    ?>
```

Comment: what is the use of determining the remaining days of customer order (Order_Date) from 365 days??? or you mean current_date from order_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code snippet

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$totalDays = $Maturity;
$usedDays = round(abs(strtotime($currentDate)-strtotime($orderdate))/86400);
$remainingDays = $totalDays-$usedDays;
```

Hope this helps you in solving the problem.